# Is there a Jenkins Plugin for creating a PR to BitBucket repo?

Tags: git, jenkins, bitbucket, pull-request

I have a repository on BitBucket, and I'm using a Jenkins pipeline script to build AMIs using packer.

Once the AMI is built successfully, I need to make changes to the code in the repository and raise a PR.

What is the simplest way to create a PR from Jenkins to a BitBucket repository?

Answer (score 0):

From a Jenkins sh/bat step, you can use curl to call the BitBucket API and [create a pull request](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/bitbucket/rest/api-group-pullrequests/#api-repositories-workspace-repo-slug-pullrequests-post)

```sh
curl https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/my-workspace/my-repository/pullrequests \
    -u my-username:my-password \
    --request POST \
    --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    --data '{
        "title": "My Title",
        "source": {
            "branch": {
                "name": "staging"
            }
        }
    }'
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer!
Is there any plugin to make the whole process easier?

Comment: @SujithK In declarative fashion: https://plugins.jenkins.io/http_request/